# svg - Could someone please write me a simple code that fades in text then ends after 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm having a very hard time trying to do a simple svg fade in effect. I'm trying to fade in three words. Would like to have the words fade in one at a time and append them and have them stay on the page for 5 seconds and then disappear and end the svg.

Example: fade in Word 1  then fade in Word 2 then fade in Word 3 pause for 5 seconds disappear and then end svg. This is my intro to a parallax site.

Please I'm very new at svg, and I can only find word typing. That's not what I'm trying to do.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-180 5 700 300" xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink"; version="1.1"> 
  <path id="path"> 
    <animate attributeName="d" from="m0,110 h0" to="m0,110 h1100" dur="7.8s" begin="0s" repeatCount="once" /> 
  </path>
  <text font-size="30" font-family="arial" fill="#ff5722"> 
    <textPath xlink:href="#path"> Word 1 Word 2 Word 3 </textPath> 
  </text> 
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try? This is not a code writing service

Comment: We can't help unless you share some code.

Comment: The only code I could find types out the words. I would like to fade in he complete words one at a time.

Comment: <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-180 5 700 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
            <path id="path">
                <animate attributeName="d" from="m0,110 h0" to="m0,110 h1100" dur="7.8s" begin="0s" repeatCount="once" />
            </path>
            <text font-size="30" font-family="arial" fill="#ff5722">
                <textPath xlink:href="#path">
                   Word 1 Word 2 Word 3
                </textPath>
            </text>
        </svg>

Comment: sorry it looks like that I couldn't figure out how to post it like regular code

Comment: I can see my code at the top of the page. Can anyone change it from typing in the words to fade in the words one at a time

Answer (score 0):

Like this. Rather than animate the path, break the words into tspan elements and animate the fill-opacity of the tspan elements.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-180 5 700 300" xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink"; version="1.1"> 
  <path id="path" d="m0,110 h1100"/> 
  <text font-size="30" font-family="arial" fill="#ff5722"> 
    <textPath xlink:href="#path"><tspan fill-opacity="0"><animate id="animation1" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="2s" to="1" fill="freeze"/>Word 1 </tspan><tspan fill-opacity="0"><animate attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="2s" begin="animation1.end" to="1" fill="freeze" />Word 2</tspan></textPath> 
  </text> 
</svg>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I'm trying to add one more word but I cannot figure out how to. Could you please show how I could add another word. Word 3. But thank you for our help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: word 3 is pretty much identical to word 2. You'd need to give word 2's animate element an id so you can do <id of animation 2>.end in word 3's animation just like I did for word 2's animation where it waits for the end of the word 1 animation.

Comment: I have this but the code ends before Word 3 displays

Comment: <tspan fill-opacity="0"><animate id="animation1" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="2s" to="1" fill="freeze"/>Word 1 </tspan>
     <tspan fill-opacity="0"><animate id="animation2" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="2s" begin="animation1.end" to="1" fill="freeze" />Word 2</tspan>
     <tspan fill-opacity="0"><animate attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="2s" begin="animation2.end" to="1" fill="freeze" />Word 3</tspan>

Comment: How doI display my code in a normal code display in when I comment back to you?

Comment: Thank you. The code does work. There was something else on my page that was making it stop early. Thanks for your help